# Looking for pointer to code that reads and parses ConfigurationProperties in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

Objective: I would like to extract the code that S.B. uses to read and parse `application.properties` into a stand-alone module that I can use like this:

```
var config = parseConfig(Config.class);
```

`parseConfig` will take of parsing `application.properties` or `application.yml` and also override the values in `application.properties` or `application.yml` with system properties or environment variables as the case may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many aspects to this question, as [configuration support in Spring covers various features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files):

- locating and ordering various configuration sources, from environment to yaml and properties files
- Spring profile support
- imports and extension mechanisms
- annotation model support, like `@ConfugirationProperties`
- JSON metadata generation for those properties (typically for IDEs)
- Binding
- Validation

Lots of it is located in the ["org.springframework.boot.context.properties package"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties) but this also depends on some support provided by Spring Framework directly. I must say that extracting this from Spring and retaining the same behavior will be a non-trivial project as this has evolved quite a bit over the years and limiting the scope there is quite hard.